# How to find if file has changed using git2r

Tags: r, libgit2

Say I have a repository `repo`:

```
library(git2r)
repo <- repository(".")
```

In this repository is a subdirectory `R`, with files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and other files that I'm not interested in. How can I use `git2r` to work out if there are unstaged changes in these files? I've looked at `summary(diff())`, but that works on the level of the whole repo.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is replicate the effects of the git command:

```
! git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- file
```

Where if there are changes in the file, then return false. While I could use a system command, there's no guarantee the user has `git` in their path and so the command would fail.

Is there a way to replicate the git functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved in the [latest development release of git2r](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/commit/d5cf226f06443f34e6c903f19ad7851a17315cbe).
There is now an `all_unstaged` option to `status`:

```
> status(repo, all_untracked = TRUE)
Untracked files:
    Untracked:  untracked/a.txt
    Untracked:  untracked/b.txt
```